# primefaces orderlist not getting updated with the changed order

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces `p:orderList` which is displayed in a popup on click of a button. When I change the order of Items in the orderlist, and click on **Save Order** button on the popup, I'm not seeing the list with the changed order. PFB my code -

```
<p:commandButton ajax="true" id="toolOrderButton" value="Tool Order" onclick="toolOrderPopup.show()" type="button"/>
<p:dialog header="Tool Order" severity="alert" widgetVar="toolOrderPopup"
                        appendToBody="true">  
    <p:orderList id="toolOrderList" controlsLocation="right" value="#{toolBean.toolOrderList}" var="tool" itemLabel="#{tool}" itemValue="#{tool}" iconOnly="true"/>
    <p:commandButton ajax="true"  value="Save Order" process="@this" type="submit" actionListener="#{toolBean.setToolOrder}" oncomplete="toolOrderPopup.hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="toolOrderPopup.hide()" type="button"/>   
</p:dialog>
```

In the bean:

```
public void setToolOrder(){ 
    System.out.println("toolOrderList-" + BeanStringConverter.convertToString(toolOrderList));
}
```

Please let me know what could be wrong with the code.

Comment: the button on the popup - Sorry, it's called "Save Order"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to process the `p:orderlist` to get the `orderList` model saved:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="true" value="Save Order" 
                 process="@this toolOrderList"
                 actionListener="#{toolBean.setToolOrder}"
                 oncomplete="toolOrderPopup.hide()"/>
```

Unrelated to your question you probably have something like:

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="toolOrderButton" value="Tool Order" onclick="toolOrderPopup.show()" type="button"/>
    ...
    <p:dialog header="Tool Order" severity="alert" widgetVar="toolOrderPopup"
                    appendToBody="true">  
        <p:orderList id="toolOrderList" controlsLocation="right" value="#{toolBean.toolOrderList}" var="tool" itemLabel="#{tool}" itemValue="#{tool}" iconOnly="true"/>
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" value="Save Order" 
                         process="@this" 
                         actionListener="#{toolBean.setToolOrder}" 
                         oncomplete="toolOrderPopup.hide()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" 
                         onclick="toolOrderPopup.hide()" type="button"/>   
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

if so, then see what primefaces doc says about `appentToBody`:

> Use appendToBody with care as the page definition and html dom would be different, for
>   example if dialog is inside an h:form component and appendToBody is enabled, on the browser
>   dialog would be outside of form and may cause unexpected results. In this case, nest a form inside
>   a dialog.

An alternative structure could be the following:

```
    <h:form id="first">
        ...
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="toolOrderButton" value="Tool Order" onclick="toolOrderPopup.show()" type="button"/>
        ...
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Tool Order" severity="alert" widgetVar="toolOrderPopup"
                    appendToBody="true">
        <h:form id="second">
            <p:orderList id="toolOrderList" controlsLocation="right" value="#{toolBean.toolOrderList}" var="tool" itemLabel="#{tool}" itemValue="#{tool}" iconOnly="true"/>
            <p:commandButton ajax="true"  value="Save Order"
                             process="@this toolOrderList" 
                             actionListener="#{toolBean.setToolOrder}" oncomplete="toolOrderPopup.hide()"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="toolOrderPopup.hide()" type="button"/>
        </h:form> 
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: The `update` is unnecessary if there are no server side changes during processing which should be reflected when the response returns. The `process` is the key. It basically specifies which inputs should be submitted. With `@this` basically only the button's own action will be invoked and no one of the inputs will be submitted.

Comment: I changed code to have process="@this toolOrderList", and removed appendToBody="true" from p:dialog, and it worked! Thanks akoskm and BalusC!